# how to share the deeplink to social app with param react native?

Tags: react-native

I spent much time researching the flow of the deep link. I want to share my deep-link to social apps like Facebook, Instagram, Mess .. . But my browser is not open this link eg: myapp://deeplink example. Some blogs were not clear on this issue. I try to open the web browser by open on the href but it seems not to work for safari. someone can give me some idea? Thanks!

Comment: maybe this video can help......https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gN4PM18yJaQ&t=1s

Comment: thanks!. my config is the same as this video. but when I click the link it not open the app. I share it on my Skype. when I click, it'll open default in my browser and shows a pop-up. for ios, it only shows on Safari. I use React Native not Expo but I think it is the same. i think in this video it shows on mail. so it can open without redirecting to the browser.